# How do I find dy/dx in terms of the variable x.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

In the attached problem there are two parts I had to figure out. For part a) I had to find dy/dx in terms of the variable t using the information stated in the top. However, I'm not confident about my answer for part b). Can anyone check to see that I have answered part b) correctly? My answer for part b) is at the bottom right of the image. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You mean bottom right. Just out of curiosity, was this given in a math curriculum?

Comment: Do you mean like in my class?

Comment: Yes, are you doing a maths degree?

Comment: And yes I meant bottom right, sorry about that

Comment: I am not doing a math degree I am a high school student

Comment: I see. Thanks. I was wondering, because usually only physicists manipulate derivatives like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work is correct except for a minus sign. In your final answer, the denominator is $x^3-3x^2+3x\mathbf{-}1$, not $x^3-3x^2+3x\mathbf{+}1$? The correct answer has a minus sign. I'll just note there's a slightly easier way.
$$y=\frac{x^2}{x^2-2x+1}=\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^2$$
so
$$y'= 2\frac{x}{x-1}\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)'$$

Comment: my denominator is x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x + 1

Comment: The correct sign is a minus before the $1$. It seems that you factorized correctly but then copied wrong? $x^4-4x^3+6x^2-6x+1=(x-1)(x^3-3x^2+3x-1)$.

Comment: possibly, I will check to see what mistake I have made

Comment: @P1081 I can see in that bubble that you did the factorization correctly. Your answer is not, though.

Comment: Yes, I did copy that wrong, wow thank you for catching that mistake. So does everything else seem correct?

Comment: It seems so. Note that the derivative can be obtained with less computation.

Comment: Yes, I did not realize that before, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The answer for a) if you need it is simple. $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}.$ Substitute $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = 2t$ and $\dfrac{dx}{dt}= \dfrac{1}{(1+t)^2}.$

So we have $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2t(1+t)^2$ and $x=1-\dfrac{1}{1+t}.$ Then $1+t = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$ and $t=\dfrac{1}{1-x}-1.$ Just substitute the values into the expression for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ to get your answer.